# Redirect all url to non-www HTTPS affecting all other domains in root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a cpanel account with **maindomain.com** and many other domains inside it.I used below code to Redirect all url to non-www HTTPS and put the .htaccess in root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

But this is affecting all other domains too in ftp account , how to make this work only for the domain i want..For example **maindomain.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a **single rule** like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted my question too..I upvoted for u

Comment: yes someone downvoting out of ignorance. I have upvoted your question, hope this answer works for you.